# Unexpected tags added automatically to my web document in Mozilla firefox

Tags: html, firefox

Is there anybody out there to tell me why these 2 tags add to my web html page automatically in mozilla firefox?!!

```
<script src="http://firefox.dealply.com/version_content.js?partner=c2s&channel=c2sp201&appTitle=" type="application/x-javascript">
<script src="http://firefox.dealply.com/firefox_1349358961357/firefox_content.js?sg=&partner=dealplydef&channel=dealplydef" type="application/x-javascript">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have [DealPly](http://download.cnet.com/DealPly/3000-2378_4-12053739.html) installed. See [Mozilla Support](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/935034)

Comment: What is DealPly ? I did not have installed something like that!!!!

Comment: See the links in the answer. It claims to be software that finds you deals. It is widely considered to be malware.

Comment: Is there any relation between Click2save or DealPly? I unistall Click2Save ,and it solved

Comment: Probably a name change to try to escape a bad reputation

Comment: Maybe , I accept your answer because you gave me this idea to search for my solution in my mozilla addons , but please mentioned about Click2Save in your answer , Thanks anyway

Comment: When I google "Click2Save", I get a bunch of links to a digital bible.

Answer (score 0):

Dealply is a malware. You should remove it. Try to follow these instructions www.americanpendulum.com/en/2013/03/18/dealply-removal/
Do you have an antimalware tool? If yes, use it and do a scan after the manual removal.